# truncation of strings, specifically a comma at the end.

Tags: objective-c, string, truncation

I need to truncate a comma at the end of a string, sort of like this:

```
NSString *string = @" this text has spaces before and after ";
NSString *trimmedString = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                     [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```

instead of whitespaceCharacterSet is there something like commaCharacterSet ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If every string has a comma/white space at the beginning and end:

```
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(1, [string length-1]);
NSString *trimmedString = [string substringWithRange:range];
```

if you just want to trim the comma:

```
[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@","];
```